# Django - How to join two querysets with different key values (but from same model)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to join two querysets in Django with different key values, but from the same model, is there any way to do so?

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class CustomerInformation(models.Model):
    status = (
        ('lead', 'Lead'),
        ('client', 'Client'),
    )

    customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=status, default='lead')
    conversion_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.localdate)


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.customer_id:
            if self.status != CustomerInformation.objects.get(customer_id=self.customer_id).status and self.status == 'client':
                self.conversion_date = timezone.now()
            elif self.status != CustomerInformation.objects.get(customer_id=self.customer_id).status and self.status == 'lead':
                self.conversion_date = None
        super(CustomerInformation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here is my filtering

```
start = date.today() + relativedelta(days=-30)

client_qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(conversion_date__gte=start).values(date=F('conversion_date')).annotate(client_count=Count('date'))
lead_qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(created_date__gte=start).values(date=F('created_date')).annotate(lead_count=Count('date'))
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to get the count of CustomerInformation instances created in the past 30 days (by annotating the count of the field 'created_date'). Also, I want to get the count of CustomerInformation instances that have converted to 'client' status within the past 30 days (by annotating the count of the field 'conversion_date'). Is there any way for me to do so and receive them in a single queryset, preferably with a single date field?

For example, my desired output would be

```
[ {'date': '170620', 'lead_count': 2, 'client_count': 1}, {'date': '180620', 'lead_count': 1, 'client_count': 0 }, ... ]
```

All help is appreciated, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same by doing:

```
combined_qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(created_date__gte=start, conversion_date__gte=start).annotate(lead_count=Count('created_date'), client_count=Count('conversion_date')
```

Note that the above will use `AND` the filter. Roughly that means it will only return customer information that have both `created_date` and `conversion_date` greater than `date`.( I might be wrong but I think that's what you want in this case).

Otherwise you can use the `Q` object for a more complex query.

```
from django.db.models import Q
combined_qs = CustomerInformation.objects.filter(Q(created_date__gte=start)|Q(conversion_date__gte=start)).annotate(lead_count=Count('created_date'), client_count=Count('conversion_date')
```

The official doc for using the Q objects is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

I will say try both and compare the results you get.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer, but the issue with that is that when i annotate the counts, it does not group the queryset but the dates only, as there is both 'conversion_date' and 'created_date', but what I would want is for it to only have 1 'date', and then it would contain the clients converted on that day, and the leads generated for that day, regardless of whether it is based on 'conversion_date' or 'created_date'